# Finding the Unicode codepoint of a character in GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, unicode

In XEmacs this is done by the calling the function char-to-ucs on a character.  GNU Emacs does not seem to have this function.  In GNU Emacs, characters seem to be ordinary integers.  Running C-x = on a latin character reveals that the Emacs codepoint is different from the Unicode codepoint for the corresponding character.  How do I find the Unicode codepoint of the character at point in GNU Emacs?

Answer (score 52):

In a modern Emacs, M-x describe-char will tell you about the character at point.
An example:

```
  character: ¢ (2210, #o4242, #x8a2, U+00A2)
    charset: latin-iso8859-1
         (Right-Hand Part of Latin Alphabet 1 (ISO/IEC 8859-1): ISO-IR-100.)
 code point: #x22
     syntax: w  which means: word
   category: l:Latin
buffer code: #x81 #xA2
  file code: #xC2 #xA2 (encoded by coding system utf-8)
    display: by this font (glyph code)
     -apple-monaco-medium-r-normal--12-120-72-72-m-120-mac-roman (#xA2)
```

Note the U+00A2 in the first part, which gives the Unicode codepoint of the character.

Comment: describe-char is bound to C-x = in Emacs 23.
Place your cursor (also called "point") over a char and go C-u C-x =

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the quick answers.  I looked at the source code for describe-char, and found the following snippet which solves my problem.  I tested it in both XEmacs 21.4.13 Mule and GNU Emacs 22.1.1 and it seems to work.

```
(or (get-char-property (point) 'untranslated-utf-8)
    (encode-char (char-after) 'ucs))
```